# Text size with line breaks

Tags: jquery, css, text

I have the following function to calculate max size of text:

```
        function MyFitText(width, height, text)
        {
            var ourText = $('span').css('font-weight', 'bold').text(text);
            var fontSize = 20;
            ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
            do {
                fontSize = fontSize - 1;
                textHeight = ourText.height();
                textWidth = ourText.width();
                ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
            } while ((textHeight > height || textWidth > width) && fontSize > 1);

            return fontSize;
        }
```

it works for one-line text, but how to calculate it for 2 and more lines? Debugger in Chrome says the following:
[image]

so, line breaks exist, but it calculates like it's one-line text.

**MODIFY**

I have modified my function by the following way (thanks gaetanoM):

```
        function MyFitText(width, height, text)
        {
            var ourTextArr = [];

            var texts = text.split('\n');
            var fontSize = 20;
            $.each(texts, function (index, value) {
                if (value != '') {
                    var ourText = $('span').css('font-weight', 'bold').text(value);
                    ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
                    ourTextArr.push(ourText);
                }
            });

            do{
                fontSize = fontSize - 1;
                var textHeight = 0;
                var textWidth = 0;
                $.each(ourTextArr, function(index, value) {
                    textHeight += value.height();
                    if (value.width() > textWidth)
                        textWidth = value.width();
                    value.css('font-size', fontSize);
                });
            }
            while ((textHeight > height || textWidth > width) && fontSize > 1);
            return fontSize;
        }
```

value.width()is being changed when font-size is changed, but value.height() always stay the same. Why?

Comment: I cannot understand how it can works??? This line **$('span').css('font-weight', 'bold').text(text)** returns an empty jQuery object and your **textWidth** is always null. You can test printing ourText.length. In any case, if your code works you may always split the text with: text.split('\n') and on the resulting array apply a forEach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring the height of a `<span>` won't work: inline elements will always have a height of one line-height.  If you want to measure the height of a block of text, you need to put it in a block-level element (i.e. a `<div>`.)

You're trying to fit the text within a predetermined area by adjusting the font size -- but leaving both the width and height to float around until they fit will generally give no fit (leaving one dimension or the other too large).  Instead, set the div's width to the predetermined width, then reduce the font size until the measured height is below the predetermined height:

```js
function MyFitText(width, height, text) {
  var $container = $('#container');
  $container
    .width(width) // <-- set a fixed width
    .html(text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')) // <-- (so we can measure all together instead of splitting on newlines)
    .css('font-weight', 'bold'); // <-- probably belongs in CSS instead
    
  for (var fontSize = 20; fontSize > 0; fontSize--) {
    $container.css('font-size', fontSize+'px');
    if ($container.height() <= height) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return fontSize;
}

// Test rig so you can play with different values:
$('#test').click(function() {
  var w = $('#w').val();
  var h = $('#h').val();
  var t = $('#t').val();
  var size = MyFitText(w,h,t);
  console.log("Set font-size to "+size+"px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Desired width: <input id="w" value="200"><br>
Desired height: <input id="h" value="400"><br>
Text: <textarea id="t">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
</textarea><br>
<button id="test">Test it</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I have size of block of text (div, span, no matter) and I have text, which should be inside, without shrink or scroll

Comment: @OlegSh thanks for clarifying; I've edited my answer now that I understand what you're trying to do.